# iOS11 - contentSize applied to wrong UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios11

With the upcoming release of iOS11, I have installed the latest version of the beta on my iPhone.

In one of my apps, I have found a bug when running on iOS11, but not on iOS10.

The issue is the following : I have a horizontal UIScrollView containing pictures (imagesScrollView) within a vertical UIScrollView, let's call this one "parentScrollView".

When calling "parentScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(...)", the contentSize is applied to imagesScrollView instead of parentScrollView on iOS11.

With the same code, the behaviour on iOS10 is I can scroll parentScrollView vertically but not imagesScrollView vertically. On iOS11, when scrolling vertically, imagesScrollView scrolls instead of parentView.

What is even weirder is imagesScrollView scrolls horizontally as expected, so the code setting its contentSize works for width, but it seems to be using parentView.contentSize height parameter.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Or could help me with this one?